# How to enable HTML tags on Wordpress Visual Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: This is the visual editor]

[[image: But the output prints out also the html tags.[2]]

How can I make html tags behave normally on this visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Text" near by Visual (Top right side in your screenshot) and put your html there, visual is used to see visual formation of the html.

EDIT:

In your case you can use alternate way, just replace `&lt;` (html code of <) with < and `&gt;` (html code of >) with > in post content on save_post hook.

Hopes it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I mean is there any way to also put html tags on VISUAL EDITOR and work it properly when it will be displayed?. Because I need it that way, kinda weird but clients need...

Answer (score 0):

simply replace html tag '<' by `&lt;` and tag '>' by  `&gt;` in your visual editor 
hope it will work for you